# CentOS 8 Unable to connect to PostgreSQL 12 Server

Tags: postgresql, linux, psql, centos, postgresql-12

When I attempt to connect to postgres in from my linux command line, I receive the following error:

```
[lloyd@localhost ~]$ sudo -u postgres psql
could not change directory to "/home/lloyd": Permission denied
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
[lloyd@localhost ~]$
```

Here is my log file - /var/log/secure:

```
Nov 14 09:57:01 localhost sudo[33108]:   lloyd : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/lloyd ; USER=postgres ; COMMAND=/bin/psql
Nov 14 09:57:01 localhost sudo[33108]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session or user slice
Nov 14 09:57:01 localhost sudo[33108]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user postgres by (uid=0)
Nov 14 09:57:01 localhost sudo[33108]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user postgres
Nov 14 09:57:12 localhost sudo[33144]:   lloyd : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/lloyd ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/vi /var/log/secure
Nov 14 09:57:12 localhost sudo[33144]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session or user slice
Nov 14 09:57:12 localhost sudo[33144]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Any ideas as to why I'm receiving this error msg or how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Lloyd

Comment: Is the server running? How is `unix_socket_directories` configured?

Comment: Is the Postgres service running? On root user, run this command "systemctl status postgresql-12.service"
If it is not running, check "journalctl -xe" and postgresql logs.